# "not a matrix" error when I run my Rcpp cde in R

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to use `nearPD` function in my Rcpp code. Although it seems trivial, but I couldn't find why it doesn't work. It is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat eBsc(mat R){
  Rcpp::Environment Matrix("package:Matrix"); 
    Rcpp::Function nearPD = Matrix["nearPD"];
    Rcpp::List PD=nearPD(R);
    mat P = PD["mat"];
return P;   
  }
```

But when I want to test it ,e.g. as below in R:

```
A <- matrix(1, 3,3); A[1,3] <- A[3,1] <- 0
d<-eBsc(A)
```

I see this error message: `"Error in eBsc(A) : not a matrix"`.
I have to mention that the nearPD returns a list of outputs which the first one is a matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mistaken. The first element of the list is not a matrix. It is an S4 object defined in package Matrix. This works:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
S4 eBsc(NumericMatrix R){
  Rcpp::Environment Matrix("package:Matrix"); 
  Rcpp::Function nearPD = Matrix["nearPD"];
  Rcpp::List PD=nearPD(R);
  S4 P = PD["mat"];
  return P;   
}

/*** R
library(Matrix)
A <- matrix(1, 3,3); A[1,3] <- A[3,1] <- 0
eBsc(A)
  */
```

Output:

```
> library(Matrix)

> A <- matrix(1, 3,3); A[1,3] <- A[3,1] <- 0

> eBsc(A)
3 x 3 Matrix of class "dpoMatrix"
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.1035534 0.8535534 0.1035534
[2,] 0.8535534 1.2071068 0.8535534
[3,] 0.1035534 0.8535534 1.1035534
```

PS: If you need a matrix use `as.matrix` from package base (in Rcpp or in R).

PPS: Obviously, it would be more efficient not to call an R function in C++ code.

Comment: but if I want to use this matrix in some other calculations, it doesn't works. For instance if I have a mat or NumericMatrix  A, the case "A *P" doesn't work even though I use "as.matrix" command. Are there any way to convert the P (as a S4 object) to a suitable type of data inside the Rcpp code?

Comment: Yes, I explain how to convert it to a matrix in my answer.